# I am trying to unit test a custom Dialog in Android and I can't seem to instantiate it

Tags: android, unit-testing, dialog

I am unit testing an application that includes a custom dialog. This dialog inherits from `android.app.Dialog` but requires a speciall subclass of `Activity`, let's call it `CustomActivity`, that provides some functions it needs.

I want to avoid instantiating one of the Activities from the tested application since I already have tests for them. I'm unit testing, not black-box-testing, so I want to run all the public functions in the dialog. This is not possible, however, without instantiating the dialog first and that requires a `CustomActivity` instance.

I've tried to create a mock subclass of `CustomActivity` and use that to launch the dialog, but I keep running into the same problem: The test application is not looking for activities in the test-application, only in the tested application. So I get "Unable to resolve activity".

I've also tried to create the activity myself, without using `Instrumentation.launchActivity` but that requires a context, which I don't have under `InstrumentationTestCase`. If I use `AndroidTestCase` instead, the provided context (via `getContext`) is just a `ContextWrapper` which doesn't seem to wrap any context, so I'm back to square one. I need to instantiate the activity first.

I've googled quite a bit and I can't believe I am the first person ever to need to unit test a `Dialog`. It seems to me that I would need something similar to the `ActivitiTestCase2` but for dialogs that provide the necessary context.

What is the best way to create my dialog? Is there another way I haven't tried? Does anyone have an example of a custom dialog unit-test?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an object-oriented problem rather than an Android problem.  I think your core problem may be your tight coupling between the classes.  Try introducing an interface in front of CustomActivity that exposes only the functions that your dialog needs, then mock the interface in your tests, instead of trying to create a mock subclass of the activity itself.  Good luck!

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Have you actually tried this, though? Is it possible to instantiate a dialog without an Activity at all? There seems to be some tight coupling in the android system already. :)

Comment: I tried it, and as I suspected it is not possible to show the dialog without an actual Activity Context to send into it. There is a lot of Android magic going on here and I find myself struggling. Should it really be this hard to test a dialog?

Comment: I assume that the reason you mind instantiating CustomActivity is that it is difficult to deal with.  With the above technique you may still have to use an activity context, but you can use a very simple activity.  If your application doesn't already include a very simple activity, you could add a blank activity and use that in your test for the context.  Admittedly, that's not perfect, but it works.  If anyone has a better solution I'd be happy to hear it as well, and you're right in thinking that there are some flaws in the design of Android related to this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I **am** trying to instantiate my CustomActivity (an abstract class) as a mock subclass (as I describe above) and my problem is that I'm not able to instantiate it in the proper way since I don't have the  necessary prerequisites in either `InstrumentationTestCase` nor `AndroidTestCase`. The reason I'm not using the `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` is that I'm not unit testing the Activity, I'm unit testing the dialog. I'm being difficult, I know, but its an important distinction. One I might have to give up on...

Comment: Gotcha.  If it were me I would make a few concessions there, but I certainly understand where you're coming from.